# Can I dynamically update a function name in Python?

Tags: python, function, recursion, flask

I am trying to update a Python function's name incrementally based on the number of times it has been called.

An example of the original function can be seen below:

```
    def function(): 
       function.counter += 1
       return print('call 0')

function.counter = 0
```

Below is the function I would like to be generated the second time the above function is called:

```
def function1(): 
    function.counter1 += 1
    return print ('call 1')
```

And so on with each previous function call resulting in the creation of a new function which adds 1 to the previous function's name. Once function1() is called, function2() would be created, then once function 2() is called function3() would be created, and so on. Is there a straightforward way I could go about this?

Comment: I'm sure someone can write code to do this, but why would you want to do something like this? If your loop runs a million times, you want to have declared 999,999 new functions?

Comment: It's not impossible, but you're likely having a design/XY-problem here. Experienced Python programmers would not attempt to do what you are trying to do. (Unless there's a very specific context.)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Wouldn't it just be much easier to use a counter?

Comment: `return print ('call 1')` is not doing what you think it is doing.  Also your indentation is messed up

Comment: The syntax problems with your code examples make them impossible to interpret, and the general "what are you trying to do" is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You should not declare multiple functions like that, there are better ways to accomplish what you want.

### Generators

Using generators is well suited for your specific example.

```
def count(start=0):
    while True:
        yield start
        start += 1

g1 = count()
next(g1) # 0
next(g1) # 1

g10 = count(10)
next(g10) # 10
```

### `itertools` module

The previous example is already implemented by `itertools.count`.

```
from itertools import count

g1 = count()
next(g1) # 0
next(g1) # 1

g10 = count(10)
next(g10) # 10
```

### Closure

If you want a function with some state, use a closure instead of function attributes.

```
def count(start=0):
    _state = {'count': start - 1}

    def inner():
        _state['count'] += 1
        return _state['count']

    return inner

f1 = count()
f1() # 0
f1() # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be ideal approach to solve this problem,instead of creating multiple functions for each increment.Use a class and store the counter as variable and call the corresponding method to increment and get_count

```
class CouterExample(object):
    """Sample DocString:

    Attributes:
        counter: A integer tracking the current counter.
    """

    def __init__(self, counter=0):
        """Return a CounterExample object with counter."""
        self.counter = counter

    def increment(self, amount):
        """Sets the counter after increment."""
        if amount > 1:
            self.counter += amount

    def get_counter(self):
        """Return the counter value."""
        return self.counter
```